# Properly Loading DataGridView From DataReader

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

Reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at23yw2h%28vs.80%29.aspx) documentation I was unde the impression that the following code would work:

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.C_Str))
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PerformSearch", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                string SearchString = textBoxSearchSting.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("SearchString", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SearchString;

                con.Open();

                dataGridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
        finally { con.Close(); }
    }
```

Or that I could atleast use the following:

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.C_Str))
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PerformSearch", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    string SearchString = textBoxSearchSting.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("SearchString", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SearchString;

                    con.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = reader;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
            finally { con.Close(); }
        }
```

but niether of the above work. Using the below code does work, with the same search value, is the below the best way to fill my datagridview with my query though? And why won't either of the above work?

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.C_Str))
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PerformSearch", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    string SearchString = textBoxSearchSting.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("SearchString", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SearchString;

                    con.Open();                           

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt != null)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
            finally { con.Close(); }
        }
```

Below also works, would I be better of using a data adapter, for any reason?

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.C_Str))
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PerformSearch", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    string SearchString = textBoxSearchSting.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("SearchString", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SearchString;

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        da.Fill(dt);

                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt != null)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
            finally { con.Close(); }
        }
```

Comment: Just tip, i think the using statement will close the connection.

Comment: @krekkon Under this circumstance it will, but I just like to keep a Close statement any time I have an Open just in case in the future I change something or take the statements out of the using I rather not accidentally forget it is all.

Comment: For the first working solution you need two `using` statements. for the second you need `three`.

Comment: User214... As you think, if it is better for, then ok ;)